# Get differing xml tags from a karate match

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, automated-tests, karate

i need to build some custom reporting feature using karate and i need to get the xml tags/attributes that differs from a karate match operation.

In particular, i'm comparing "fresh and untested" xml responses with "old and correct" xml responses so i would like to individuate the exact tag (or tags) of the current xml response which make the match instruction fails.

Currently i'm making the comparison just checking the `res.pass` value but the `res.message` contains the whole xml response.

```
var res= karate.match(expectedResponse,currentResponse)
```

So for example, given:

```
 ...
 <name>John</name>
 <surname>Doe</surname>
 ...
```

compared with

```
...
<name>John</name> 
<surname>Boe</surname>
...
```

it returns surname as different valued tag.

Is possible to achieve this kind of detail with Karate?